# How to select threshold values automatically uses the peaks of the histogram?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

By the OpenCV library, I want to threshold an image like this:

```
threshold(image, thresh, 220, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

But I want to automatically find the threshold value (220).

I use Otsu to estimate the threshold. But it doesn't work in my case.

therefore, I should use Histogram Peak Technique. I want to find the two peaks in the histogram corresponding to the background and object of the image. It sets the threshold value automatically halfway between the two peaks. 
I use this book (pages: 117 and 496-505): "Image Processing in C" by Dwayne Phillips ([http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/](http://www.dwaynephillips.net/)). And I use source code for find the two peaks in the histogram corresponding to the background and object of the image. this is my image:

[image]

this is my c++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    Mat image0 = imread("C:/Users/Alireza/Desktop/contrast950318/2.bmp");
    imshow("image0", image0);

    Mat image, thresh, Tafrigh;
    cvtColor(image0, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);


    int N = image.rows*image.cols;

    int histogram[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    //create histo
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++){
            histogram[((int)image.at<uchar>(i, j))]++;
        }
    }


    int peak1, peak2;
    #define PEAKS 30
    int distance[PEAKS], peaks[PEAKS][2];

    int i, j = 0, max = 0, max_place = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<PEAKS; i++){
        distance[i] = 0;
        peaks[i][0] = -1;
        peaks[i][1] = -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
        max = histogram[i];
        max_place = i;

        //insert_into_peaks(peaks, max, max_place);
        //int max, max_place, peaks[PEAKS][2];
        //int i, j;
        /* first case */
        if (max > peaks[0][0]){
            for (i = PEAKS - 1; i > 0; i--){
                peaks[i][0] = peaks[i - 1][0];
                peaks[i][1] = peaks[i - 1][1];
            }
            peaks[0][0] = max;
            peaks[0][1] = max_place;
        } /* ends if */

        /* middle cases */
        for (j = 0; j < PEAKS - 3; j++){
            if (max < peaks[j][0] && max > peaks[j + 1][0]){
                for (i = PEAKS - 1; i > j + 1; i--){
                    peaks[i][0] = peaks[i - 1][0];
                    peaks[i][1] = peaks[i - 1][1];
                }

                peaks[j + 1][0] = max;
                peaks[j + 1][1] = max_place;
            } /* ends if */
        } /* ends loop over j */
        /* last case */
        if (max < peaks[PEAKS - 2][0] &&
            max > peaks[PEAKS - 1][0]){
            peaks[PEAKS - 1][0] = max;
            peaks[PEAKS - 1][1] = max_place;
        } /* ends if */

}/* ends loop over i */



    for (int i = 1; i<PEAKS; i++){
        distance[i] = peaks[0][1] - peaks[i][1];
        if (distance[i] < 0)
            distance[i] = distance[i] * (-1);
    }

    peak1 = peaks[0][1];
    cout << "  peak1= " << peak1;

    for (int i = PEAKS - 1; i > 0; i--){
        if (distance[i] > 1)
            peak2 = peaks[i][1];

    }
    cout << "  peak2= " << peak2;


    int mid_point;
    //int peak1, peak2;
    short hi, low;

    unsigned long sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    if (peak1 > peak2)
        mid_point = ((peak1 - peak2) / 2) + peak2;
    if (peak1 < peak2)
        mid_point = ((peak2 - peak1) / 2) + peak1;

    for (int i = 0; i<mid_point; i++)
        sum1 = sum1 + histogram[i];
    for (int i = mid_point; i <= 255; i++)
        sum2 = sum2 + histogram[i];
    if (sum1 >= sum2){
        low = mid_point;
        hi = 255;
    }
    else{
        low = 0;
        hi = mid_point;
    }

    cout << "  low= " << low << "  hi= " << hi;



double  threshnum = 0.5* (low  + hi);
threshold(image, thresh, threshnum, hi, THRESH_BINARY_INV);


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know this code correct is or not. If it correct, why is threshold value 202?

What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] and remove all the unneeded/commented garbage codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also the Max Entropy. In some cases using only the high frequency of the entropy could be better

```
int maxentropie(const cv::Mat1b& src)
{
    // Histogram
    cv::Mat1d hist(1, 256, 0.0);
    for (int r=0; r<src.rows; ++r)
        for (int c=0; c<src.cols; ++c)
            hist(src(r,c))++;

    // Normalize
    hist /= double(src.rows * src.cols);

    // Cumulative histogram
    cv::Mat1d cumhist(1, 256, 0.0);
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        sum += hist(i);
        cumhist(i) = sum;
    }

    cv::Mat1d hl(1, 256, 0.0);
    cv::Mat1d hh(1, 256, 0.0);

    for (int t = 0; t < 256; ++t)
    {
        // low range entropy
        double cl = cumhist(t);
        if (cl > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= t; ++i)
            {
                if (hist(i) > 0)
                {
                    hl(t) = hl(t) - (hist(i) / cl) * log(hist(i) / cl);
                }
            }
        }

        // high range entropy
        double ch = 1.0 - cl;  // constraint cl + ch = 1
        if (ch > 0)
        {
            for (int i = t+1; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                if (hist(i) > 0)
                {
                    hh(t) = hh(t) - (hist(i) / ch) * log(hist(i) / ch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // choose best threshold

    cv::Mat1d entropie(1, 256, 0.0);
    double h_max = hl(0) + hh(0);
    int threshold = 0;
    entropie(0) = h_max;

    for (int t = 1; t < 256; ++t)
    {
        entropie(t) = hl(t) + hh(t);
        if (entropie(t) > h_max)
        {
            h_max = entropie(t);
            threshold = uchar(t);
        }
    }
    if(threshold==0) threshold=255;
    return threshold;
}
```

Comment: @ Adel: Thank you so much for your code. but when I use it for my image in up, I have not good result. If it possible, please do your code on my image in up and insert your result here.

Comment: @ Adel: I use your code correctly. But Thresh number is lower than original number!!!